# How to fix errors in Google Maps API in order to integrate with Wordpress using ACF?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am unable to integrate google maps on my wordpress theme using advanced custom fields plugin. Whenever I add the map field it displays the map for sometime and gives me either darkened watermarked map saying for development purpose only or If it displays the map I unable to search the locations on it but that is also temporary again it goes to black background. Before that I was getting whole bunch of errors which I seem to fix it by seeing the document in google cloud. Still so far no solution to it. Do I really need to have billing enabled to use it or is there any word around.

I already got the API key from google ,enabled all the necessary API such as geolocation, places, maps JS API etc. I tried to enable the billing but my debit card does not have the recurring billing service available.

```
function MapKey($api){

    $api['key']="AIzaSyBK8-6Wnwbj7GeDUQ6fQ5MIJatrfWC8i7U";

    return $api;

}

add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api','MapKey');

?>
```

I do not have issue with the code as it works fine I guess. Only problem is I am unable to display the perfectly working map on my wordpress dashboard to add it to my post type.FYI I am using local host, XAMPP environment

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no way of setting up a key properly without a billing account being linked to the account containing the key

Comment: I am able to add the billing account now and the map is displayed, Now there is one issue whenever I drop the pin to a certain point, I am unable to get that address displayed

Comment: I would suggest to contact the theme/plugin's developer for assistance.

Comment: I Kinda fixed that now after enabling the billing and few api's. The map is showing now